# ЧПУ адреса, мультиязычность и канонические ссылки

Tags: seo, чпу

Есть сайт, в данный момент он работает на двух языках: en и ru.
Все отлично работает, но хотелось бы немного оптимизировать под SEO.
На сайте есть категории и контент. На разных языках разные адреса. Например, для англ.версии сайта ссылки будут иметь вид:

```
http://example.com/category/123-name-of-category
http://example.com/article/1234-name-of-article
```

Для русскоязычной версии:

```
http://example.com/category/123-nazvanie-kategorii
http://example.com/article/1234-nazvanie-stati
```

где 123 и 1234 - это ID категории и статьи в БД.

А есть еще для этих ссылок короткие варианты, типа:

```
http://example.com/cat/123
http://example.com/art/1234
```

**Вопрос:**

1) Как определить правильный канонический адрес для таких страниц?

2) Как правильно указать тег `link rel="alternate" href="http://***" hreflang="ru|en"`?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Как определить правильный канонический адрес для таких страниц?** Это зависит от уникальности содержания веб-страниц. Если содержание уникально, то указывайте в как канонический - линк данной страницы. Если содержание данной веб-страницы доступно и по другим линкам, то выберите основной линк для данного содержания и выбранную веб-страницу укажите как каноническую. Таким образом вы сообщите поисковикам о вашей веб-странице с основным содержанием. Этот же, выбранный вами основной, линк укажите в sitemap вашего веб-сайта. Для веб-страниц с неканоническим содержанием, используйте переадресацию 301 на стороне сервера, чтобы перенаправлять на него трафик с других URL. Это один из самых надежных способов. Код статуса 301 означает, что запрашиваемая страница находится по другому адресу. ***[Документация Apache о файле htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html)*** + ***[примеры переадресации](https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/seo-advice/useful-301-redirect-using-htaccess-seo)*** + ***[справка Гугл о канонических линках](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru)***.
2. **Как правильно указать тег link rel="alternate" href="http://" hreflang="ru|en"?** Согласно этой ***[справке Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=ru)*** вы можете указать для русской версии - `<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/category/123-nazvanie-kategorii" hreflang="x-default" />` совместно с указанием линка английской версии для данного содержания `<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/category/123-name-of-category" hreflang="en" />`. Для английской версии, наоборот, `<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/category/123-name-of-category" hreflang="x-default" />` совместно с указанием линка русской версии `<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/category/123-nazvanie-kategorii" hreflang="ru" />`. Согласно ***[документации Официального блога Гугл](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html)***: "*значение атрибута hreflang x-default сигнализирует нашим алгоритмам, что эта страница не нацелена на какой-либо конкретный язык или локализацию и является страницей по умолчанию, когда другая страница не подходит*". Обратите внимание, что в указанных вами линках отсутствуют папки директории или субдомены с указание языка содержания, например: **example.com/en/category/123-name-of-category** или **example.com/ru/category/123-nazvanie-kategorii**. Указание таких папок упрощает понимание структуры вашего веб-сайта.